# Bones is not influencing model correctly

Tags: rigging

im trying to use armature deform automatic weights to rigging the model. but the result is not working as expected. when i move the bone in pose mode, the bone is not influencing the mesh as expected.

[image]

here is the file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l4RbWg0g5JoTeGUaQo1kem3PuCweHggS/view?usp=sharing

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normals are inverted:

[image]

Select all in *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and parent again. That said I'm not sure about your armature, you should create some IK bones, and you should disable the *Deform* option for the bones that seem to be the controllers, otherwise they will affect the mesh as well, which they are not supposed to do.

Comment: OMG it works. you really2 saved my day. Thank you so much.